# Shapely point geometry in geopandas df to lat/lon columns

Tags: python, gis, latitude-longitude, geopandas, shapely

I have a geopandas df with a column of shapely point objects. I want to extract the coordinate (lat/lon) from the shapely point objects to generate latitude and longitude columns. There must be an easy way to do this, but I cannot figure it out.

I know you can extract the individual coordinates like this:

```
lon = df.point_object[0].x
lat = df.point_object[0].y
```

And I could create a function that does this for the entire df, but I figured there was a more efficient/elegant way.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you have the latest version of geopandas (0.3.0 as of writing), and the if `df` is a GeoDataFrame, you can use the `x` and `y` attributes on the geometry column:

```
df['lon'] = df.point_object.x
df['lat'] = df.point_object.y
```

In general, if you have a column of shapely objects, you can also use `apply` to do what you can do on individual coordinates for the full column:

```
df['lon'] = df.point_object.apply(lambda p: p.x)
df['lat'] = df.point_object.apply(lambda p: p.y)
```

Comment: I must not have the latest version because the first solution is giving me an error. But the second solution works great. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it's been a while since you answered. I tried the methods you suggested but it fails with error code `IndexError: index out of range`. Does this not work with `GeoSeries`?

Comment: edit: calling the attribute `geodataframe.point_object.x/y/z` will return error if there are empty geometries (see [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2223))

Answer (score 23):

Without having to iterate over the Dataframe, you can do the following:

```
df['lon'] = df['geometry'].x
df['lat'] = df['geometry'].y
```

Comment: I've gotten this to work before, but sometimes (with no apparent difference in the data structure) I get `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'x'`

Comment: this works in one go `df[['lat', 'lng']] = df.apply(lambda p: (p.geometry.y, p.geometry.x), axis=1, result_type='expand')`

Comment: I wonder which is fastest, doing both columns separately as in this answer, doing them separately as lambdas on series, or doing them together as a lambda on the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to extract the center point (latitude and longitude) from the polygon and multi-polygon.

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file(path + 'df.geojson')
#Find the center point
df['Center_point'] = df['geometry'].centroid
#Extract lat and lon from the centerpoint
df["long"] = df.Center_point.map(lambda p: p.x)
df["lat"] = df.Center_point.map(lambda p: p.y)
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Latitude and longitude are swapped here.